# What's the canonical punishment for Self-defending a Clan Champion to death?

Tags: l5r-4e, rokugan, crime-and-laws

### The death of the Mantis Champion

It was a winter night at [Kyuden Bayushi](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Kyuden_Bayushi), during a [Winter Court](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Winter_court), on the road leading east, and right at the edge of the town surrounding the palace. A group of young (Status 1, Insight 3) Samurai on the way to the bath and only armed with their trusty Wakizashi was afoot. They encountered the Clan Champion of the Mantis in front of a minor shrine. The Yoritomo was armed with his Daisho and transporting an ancestral weapon that belonged to the Daidoji that had been stolen long ago. When the youngsters recognized the transported blade for what it was, he did not want to give it back to the Crane - even though the imperial magistrate had ordered him and his clan to do exactly that during the hours of the day, should he have it. Nor did he take the offer to have it returned by anonymous means, appearing to have it smuggled somewhere and forgotten.

Instead of saying anything but mockery, the Daimyo of the Yoritomo and Champion of the Mantis thus drew steel and started an attack on the young Samurai. But lo and behold, the young Samurai cut him down within a couple of heartbeats: They gained the initiative, and after he tested their defenses in the first round, he was hit twice in the second round. Resorting to fleeing without saying a word of intent to surrender, one pursued the few steps and thus the daimyo was cut down with a wakizashi through the chest.

He could not be rescued, but duty called for informing the Magistrate's office of the occurrence at once so the body would not be defiled and prepared for [funeral](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Funeral).

The young samurai then brought the contraband home to the Crane, and informed their superiors... but here the story is incomplete, as it has not transpired so far.

### The Question

Undoubtedly, the Clan Champion was breaking the law at the moment, and he was offered to surrender either the contraband or accompany the youngsters. Instead, he turned the civil talk deadly and drew his Katana first, even did the first attack. Now, the situation seems Dire...

**But what does Rokugani Law say about such a situation, where a lower ranking Samurai is attacked by a higher ranking one, and defends themselves by killing the attacker?**